Trouble understanding 6in4 tunnel parameters
When I create a 6in4 tunnel (e.g. on HE), I am given a bunch of addresses and masks:
IPv6 Tunnel Endpoints:
Server IPv4 Address: 216.66.80.162
Server IPv6 Address: 2001:470:70:625::1/64
Client IPv4 Address: [redacted]
Client IPv6 Address: 2001:470:70:625::2/64
Routed IPv6 Prefixes:
Routed /64: 2001:470:71:625::/64
Routed /48: 2001:470:6297::/48

In my mind they allocate me a /64 subnet denoted routed /64. All the traffic which is supposed to go there will hit their servers and be tunnelled to me (Client Ipv4 Address) via IPv4. And to send IPv6 packets all I need to know is the Server IPv4 Address, and I simply encapsulate and send them there, claiming my IPv6 address to be Client IPv6 Address.
What I do not understand is:

Why is Client IPv6 Address not under Routed /64? How do the responses get routed back to me if my IP is not associated with my tunnel?
After setting everything up following my router's guide, the devices on the network started getting addresses under Routed /48. What is the purpose of the Client IPv6 Address then?
The guide did not ask for Server IPv6 Address, what's its purpose?


The configuration very much mimics a real connection between an ISP and a customer. Only the IPv4 endpoint addresses are a tunnel-specific parameter – everything else could just as well be seen on a physical Ethernet interface (such as the fiber-ethernet link we receive at my workplace, which in fact has similar configurations for IPv6 and IPv4).
So it will help if you first split the list of parameters into two groups, with "Client/Server IPv4" describing the 'physical layer' of the tunnel link (so to speak), the rest being the 'network layer' that runs through the tunnel.

After setting everything up following my router's guide, the devices on the network started getting addresses under Routed /48. What is the purpose of the Client IPv6 Address then?

The /64 with the "Client" and "Server" addresses is assigned to the connection between you and the ISP, which is a separate network segment from your LAN, and therefore has a separate network range/prefix.
Again, imagine the tunnel as a physical WAN interface going to HE as your ISP. In fact, Client IPv6 is essentially the same thing as your physical router's "WAN interface" address, and the Server IPv6 parameter would be the router's "default gateway".

Why is Client IPv6 Address not under Routed /64?

As said above, the two are meant to be assigned to different interfaces on the router.

How do the responses get routed back to me if my IP is not associated with my tunnel?

The mechanism is literally that they are routed to you. On the tunnel server, each of your "Routed" prefixes is configured as a static IP route that looks like (in Linux terms):
ip route add 2001:470:71:625::/64 via 2001:470:70:625::2 dev ipip12345
ip route add 2001:470:6297::/48 via 2001:470:70:625::2 dev ipip12345

Native IPv6 works the same way; e.g. getting a /64 using DHCPv6-PD causes a similar route to appear on the ISP's gateway that you connect to.
(Indeed routing in IPv4 also works the exact same way, it's just rare to get a whole public IPv4 range routed to you in comparison – without getting involved in BGP, that is.)

The guide did not ask for Server IPv6 Address, what's its purpose?

This is one part where a 6in4 (or more generally IP-in-IP) tunnel differs from Ethernet – it's a point-to-point link (like a ppp interface), with only one device on the other end.
So although I said earlier that the Server IPv6 address is your "default gateway" address, in reality the tunnel interface makes both of them irrelevant because it's technically enough to specify just the device as part of the route.
Still, HE assigns a /64 to the tunnel because that's the "more proper" way of configuring things, and because they also sell physical connectivity where the same shortcut wouldn't work, so might as well keep the process identical between both products.
(Additionally, even if you don't use the "Server IPv6" address on your side, HE does use the "Client IPv6" address on their side for a different purpose – they ping your router on occasion to make sure the tunnel is active, and will remove it after several months of no response. So if your router's firmware has been made with HE in mind, the manufacturer knows that the "Client IPv6" address needs to be set up for the aliveness check, even if it's not actually necessary for tunnel operation.)

A couple questions:

So Server / Client IPv6 Addresses are just identifiers and could as well have been absolutely random IPv6 addresses, i.e. they do not make any sense for anyone else but me and HE?






HE does use the "Client IPv6" address on their side for a different purpose – they ping your router on occasion to make sure the tunnel is active.

So HE pings this "virtual" client IP "within" the tunnel, and not my router's actual IPv6 visible to the rest of the internet?


Not exactly. In your case they're completely real IPv6 addresses, in the same way as your IPv4 WAN address is real. Though it would indeed be possible to use private addresses for this purpose, but that's nothing unique to 6in4 or IPv6 anyway, and even then they would still remain actual addresses and not just identifiers.



The "Client IPv6" address is your router's actual IPv6 visible to the rest of the internet. The fact that it's assigned to a tunnel interface doesn't change that; it's still as real as the one assigned to the LAN interface. (I keep repeating the point: ignore that it's a tunnel and pretend that it's a physical connection.)


The fact that my router is accessible by the "Client IPv6" feels more like a coincidence rather than a necessity: It just happens that HE has this address routed to them, and they have it routed to me. Why not use a private address? And if you really want "Client IPv6" to actually be the address of my router, why not make it under "Routed /48", say the 0-th address of this subnet? This way you would only need one "ip route add 2001:470:6297::/48 dev ipip12345" and that's all the routing required for me.


A router doesn't have a "the address", it has one address for each network that it's connected to. 1) It's neither necessity nor coincidence – an optional thing can still be done deliberately, for the sake of consistency or other reasons. 2) Some ISPs do use private addresses for their point-to-point links, but it makes things a bit more consistent (and more flexible) to treat every network segment equally, when there's no necessity to invent special cases to squeeze out the last bits of addressing efficiency.



Your suggested "ip route add 2001:470:6297::/48 dev ipip12345" would already work with an IP-IP tunnel without any special cases, but when applied to e.g. regular Ethernet interfaces (where MAC addresses and ARP/NDP exist), a route without a gateway already has a specific meaning (that the specified prefix is directly on link), so you can't really change it to it mean "route through the 0th address of this subnet" instead, especially as the router most likely won't answer ARP/ND queries for that address anyway.


In general it sounds like you're reading this under the assumption that the routed prefixes would always be immediately assigned to the 1st router that is connected to the ISP. That does not have to be the case – once the customer is assigned the /48 they are free to do anything they want with that, e.g. assign pieces of it to other routers two, three hops away and route them internally; they're not required to configure address 1 of subnet 0 on the initial router, even if that's what your router does by default.

So giving the client an address outside of routed prefix is basically a convention, which helps the customer do routing more neatly and is inspired by physical cable connections?

Yes, it pretty much just allows the customer's router to have an address without forcing them to do their routing in a specific way. Same applies to both IPv4 (where /30 or /31 is common) and IPv6 (where /127 or /64 would be used). Though on the other hand, unnumbered point-to-point links exist in physical connections too, they're not a concept unique to tunnels – often it comes down to the network engineer's preference (and the link's usage, e.g. a provider-customer link vs an ISP-internal link between routers).
